# Powers of polylogarithms

Tags: integration, power-series, polylogarithm

I would like to take powers of arbitrary order to polylogarithm functions. For instance, given
$$
\text{Li}_\alpha(z) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{z^k}{k^\alpha}
$$
I am interested in
$$
[\text{Li}_\alpha(z)]^m = \left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{z^k}{k^\alpha}\right) ^m
$$

Of particular interest is how the integral representation

$$
\text{Li}_\alpha(z) = \frac{z}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\int^\infty_0dt \frac{t^{\alpha-1}}{e^t-z}
$$
would behave in this case. Does anyone know of research in this area ?

Comment: Why do the summations start from $k=0$ rather than $k=1$?

Answer (score 0):

well:
$$\ln(1+z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}x^k$$
so:
$$\ln(1-z)=-\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k}$$
$$\therefore \operatorname{Li}_1^m(z)=(-1)^m\ln^m(1-z)$$

---

If we first try and start with a function of the form:
$$\frac{d}{dx}\operatorname{Li}_a(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^{k^a-1}=\frac1x\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^{k^a}$$
maybe there is a way to find a function that is represent by this? :)